# Preserved properties of lebesgue measures under weak-* convergence

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have got a question about the weak-* limit of lebesgue measures.

Assume that there exists a weak-* limit $\mu^*$ of measures $\mu_m$ which $\mu_m$(s) are lebesgue measures.

> What could we say about the type of the measure $\mu^*$ ? Are the properties of $\mu_m$(s) preserved under weak-* convergence? Is $\mu^*$ a lebesgue measure too?

Comment: What do you mean by Lebesgue measures? What is the underlying space?

Comment: @coudy $\mu_m$(s) are are renormalisations of the Lebesgue measure to some sets $A_m$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not a Lebesgue measure in general. Let us work on $[0,1]$ and denote by $\lambda$ the Lebesgue measure on the interval. Take for example $\mu_n$ defined as
$$
\mu_n(A) = n \mu(A\cap [0,1/n]), \quad \int f d\mu_n = n \int_0^{1/n} f(x) \, dx.
$$
The sequence $\mu_n$ is weakly converging to the Dirac measure $\delta_0$. This is not a Lebesgue measure.

Let us prove the convergence. For all continuous $f$, and using the change of variables $y=nx$,
$$
\int f\, d\mu_n = n\int_0^{1/n} f(x) dx = \int_0^1 f\left({y\over n}\right) dy
\longrightarrow f(0) = \int f\, d\delta_0
$$
by continuity of $f$ at $0$ and the dominated convergence theorem.